# On page load - Knockout / Javascript has a 1-4 second delay

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Im using MVC4, Knockout and the Knockout.Mapping plugin.

On the initial load of the page, everything renders except for the part that knockout is rendering, sometimes there is a 1-4 second delay until the javascript / knockout loads this section. Initially during testing there was very little data and this really wasn't a issue, however with lots of data its very obvious and most importantly just looks very unprofessional.

Here is our loading script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ordersViewModel = new ordersViewModel('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))');
        ko.applyBindings(ordersViewModel);
    });
</script>
```

My guess is that I can use "Display: none" or hide that section until the javascript has loaded, I would like to do something similar to Github where they have a loading dialog over the content that it is fetching.

I'm sure someone has come across this issue and has an elegant solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers, 
Sam

Comment: Are you loading jQuery / knockout just before the closing body tag or in the header?

Comment: Im willing to bet it has to do with mapping so much data.  Does all your data need to be observable?  Or could you apply pagination?

Comment: @Gabriel - I use @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) and its just before the closing body tag. So not in the header.

Comment: @latr0dectus - I also have no doubt that mass data has an effect, however it still exists for say 5 items, but when I say exists, I mean unless your looking for it you wont notice it. e.g. 300 ms delay.

Comment: Your bindings won't be apply as long as your JS scripts won't be loaded. This will be perceived lag on the client side. If you put them in the head section the JS files will be loaded before your DOM and you won't need the `$(function () {}` part around your binding code. This will be perceived lag on the download. Try it out and see witch one matches the most with your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the CSS route as you discussed in your question. The easiest way is to simply have two containers, one containing the data that is loading and one containing a typical loading message, perhaps with a gif indicating that loading is taking place (like those found here http://www.ajaxload.info/).

So all you need to do is put the containers one after another:

```
<div id="loadingMessage">
    My loading message
</div>
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
    My content
</div>
```

Then execute this JS once the binding has completed:

```
$("#loadingMessage, #content").toggle();
```